# PHP sessions error with custom wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am getting a **sessions error** on **Wordpress** Site.
I have a custom WordPress Plugin, it has multi-step paginated forms that the client progress from one page to the next, so i have to save chosen options in a session, and on the last step i have some kind of overview of the booking

**Critical errors** I am receiving:  **A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests.**

I think the session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests?

I tried many changes, nothing work
if i replace  session_start with --> session_start(['read_and_close' => true]);
the error will go away, but the session will completely lost.

this is part of the main file of the plugin

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Appointment
 * Description: This plugin adds form to create appointmentswith SOAP authorization
 * Version: 12
 * Author: YQ
 **/

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die( 'Invalid request.' );
}

define("OA_OSCAR_EMR_TZ", "America/New_York");
define("VALIDATE_CAPTCHA", true);
define( 'XHE_HCV_DISABLE_HIN', true);
define( 'XHE_HCV_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'XHE_HCV_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Oscar' ) ) :
    class WP_Oscar
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            require_once XHE_HCV_DIR . 'includes/class-email.php';
            require_once XHE_HCV_DIR . 'includes/class-ajax.php';
            require_once XHE_HCV_DIR . 'includes/class-register-users.php';
            

              add_action('init', array( $this, 'session_start' )  );
        //    add_action('init', array( $this, 'session_close' ), 9999999);
        //    add_action( 'wp_logout', array( $this, 'session_end' ) );
        //    add_action( 'wp_login',array( $this,  'session_end' ) );
            
            // shortcodes to process confirm and cancel links
            add_shortcode( 'oscar_appointment', array($this, 'display_shortcode') );
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ), 999 );
            add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts_admin' ), 999 );

            add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'admin_menu'));
            add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'register_settings'));
        }
        

         public function session_start() {
             if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE && !headers_sent()) {
                 session_start();
                 }
                 }

          public function session_end() {
                     session_destroy();
         } 

   
        public function display_shortcode()
        {
            global $wp_query;

            $query_var = get_query_var('wp_oscar');

            if( $query_var == 'confirm' || $query_var == 'cancel' ) {
                $this->display_confirm($query_var);
            }else {
                $this->display_form();
            }

            wp_enqueue_style( 'venobox-style' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.blockUI' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.venobox' );
            wp_enqueue_script('xhe-hcv');
            wp_enqueue_script('zinput');
            
        }

        private function display_form() {
            $steps = array(
                'init' => XHE_HCV_DIR . 'templates/html-init.php',
                'register' => XHE_HCV_DIR . 'templates/html-new-client.php',
                'hin' => XHE_HCV_DIR . 'templates/html-hin.php',
                'email' => XHE_HCV_DIR . 'templates/html-email.php',
                'booking_time' => XHE_HCV_DIR . 'templates/html-booking-time.php',
                'confirm' => XHE_HCV_DIR . 'templates/html-confirm.php'
            );

            echo '<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>';

            $xhe_hcv_term_pageid = $this->get_option_value('oscar_emr_plugin_options', 'oa_oscar_emr_xhe_hcv_term_pageid');

            if( $xhe_hcv_term_pageid ) {
                $term_page = get_post( absint($xhe_hcv_term_pageid) );

                if( ! empty($term_page->post_content) ) {
                    printf(
                        '<div id="openTermModal" class="venobox-modal">%s</div>',
                        $term_page->post_content
                    );
                }
            }
............................
```